# How to escape a backslash

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to replace a `(` with `\(` using a regular expression in perl. This is proving to be problematic.

```
$var =~ s/\(/\\\(/g
```

does not seem to work. The expression is not escaping the backslash a second time and the result is `\\(`

Any tricks to make this work?

Thanks.

You guys were right. My code does work. It was displaying differently in the command line because it was not interpreting it. Sorry for the wasted time.

Comment: Wait so, do you want to replace it with `\(` or `\\(`? Your replacement result should be `\(`.

Comment: show us the other part of your code

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you going to want to do the same thing with closed parenthesis later? Or are you only escaping open parens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$var =~ s/\(/\\\\\(/g
```

Comment: I've tried it from one \ to 10 \'s. Did not get the intended result. :( Frustrating

Comment: And the intended result is for there to be *2* backslashes after? If you tried from one \ to 10 \'s, show us the result of these attempts.

Comment: Just one. Want to replace ( with \( .....the reason being that I'm sending a command to the terminal via a cgi script. Some of the filename's have ('s in them. Need to escape them before I can do stuff.

Comment: `s/\(/\\\(/g` should be working. If it is not working something is horribly wrong. More likely, something else is happening in your code that affects the results.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape `\`

```
perl -e '$var = "((test))"; $var =~ s/\(/\\\\\(/g; print $var'
\\(\\(test))
```

Comment: That does not seem to escape it either :(

Comment: @Falcata Stop saying "that doesn't work" and start making your question clearer as to what would happen when it does work.

Comment: Sorry if I was being ambigious. Replace a ( with  \(

Comment: Your original code *does* that so stop looking for the error in the code that's *good*. Now, post your whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ocde that you are looking for, replace "/" with another
delimiter it will make it easy.

```
$abc =~ s#\(#\\\(#g;
```